# Clear grid store baseParams or reset them?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid list which I populate the baseParams using setBaseParam() method and then in a later event I clear the baseParams like so:

```
workorder_list_primary.store.baseParams = {};
workorder_list_primary.store.load();

console.log(workorder_list_primary.store);
```

But this isn't working? I need to reset the filter criteria completely. I have tried using load() and reload() -- any ideas?

Comment: Are you using filters or baseParams? What Ext version? Why didn't you post the part of the code where you're actually setting those options?

Comment: provide the version of extjs you're using make the way to the others to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the use of `setBaseParam()` which is only available in ExtJS 3.4 I guees you are using version 3.x

Based on the source of store this makes no sense because `baseParams = {}` will definitely override the params. Other params will be pushed by paging, can be added to the load call or can be added within a 'beforeload' eventhandler. You may need to check all of them.

Comment: I am running 3.2.1 to be exact...I see now what the problem is...I am custom handling "beforeload" in the minimize event and overriding the fact I blanked the filter out...